# Process more of my ASP.NET Page after streaming PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have looked at previous questions but nothing seems to answer what I am trying to do.

I am creating a Cashiering Function in my ASP.NET C# application.  I am using jQuery Modal Dialog with an Animated GIF display when the users clicks the PROCESS button to process the payment.  This adds the modal dialog box to the screen, with the animated GIF and prevents the user from processing more than once.  This works great....

Now what I would like to do is present the user with the receipt for the transaction as a PDF.  I have code that will stream the PDF to the user after processing the full transaction.

As such:

```
        // Stream the Report
        thePage.Response.ContentType = contenttype;
        thePage.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PT_APPOBJECTS.MakeValidFileName(OutputFilename)));
        thePage.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        thePage.Response.End();
```

The issue is, that my MODAL Dialog box is still on the screen with my nice little animated GIF.  I can't seem to send anything else back in the response.  I need the ability to close my jQuery Dialog box with javascript once the PDF is streamed.

I don't really want to re-direct to another page either to stream the PDF.

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: Yeap... Nope... After `BinaryWrite` you cannot write anything else... You will have to rethink the way it is currently working. Had the same issue, Used Ajax, saved the PDF in another path, sent the path back to client and from client opened the link in popup

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of using Ajax too... I build the report in memory, so there is no PDF as a file... I will think of something... thanks.

Comment: Well, I have saved the file in a temporary folder, and each time a pdf gets saved in that folder, I delete the other pdf's older than an hour or so because its web, so the files wont be needed after a while. Also use GUID to make sure the file name is always unique.